# Call a column name when for each value when using the apply() function in r

Tags: arrays, r, apply

I want to transform the third dimension of data for my 3 dimensional array-

```
> my.array
, , 1

   0 90 45
1 -1 -4 -7
2 -2 -5 -8
3 -3 -6 -9
```

The column names are latitudes and the row names are based on a height above ground level. The function that needs to be performed depends on latitude so, is there a way that I can call the column name and use it as an integer in the equation? If not, is there another way that you would suggest?

For example-

```
>my.fun <- function(x, current.column.name){
>y <- x*sin(current.column.name)
>x <- x*cos(current.column.name)
>}

>apply(my.array, c(1,2), my.fun)
```

The ultimate goal would be to get it to process each value using the column name, so the function would compute as such for my.array[1,2,1] -

```
y <- -4*sin(90)
x <- -4*cos(90)
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'm not a fan of storing that much information in column names, so I wrote a solution thats a bit different than you asked. As you've probably noticed, R and numerical column names don't always work well. So here is a solution that turns your data to a long format, and calculates the x's and y's. I kept `my.array` as a list, so the solution should be easily scalable.

```
my.array <- list('1'=read.table(text="0 90 45
1 -1 -4 -7
2 -2 -5 -8
3 -3 -6 -9",header=T,check.names=F))



library(reshape2)


melted_arrays <- lapply(my.array,function(x){
  x <- data.frame(x, check.names=F)
  x$height <- as.numeric(rownames(x))
  melt_x <- melt(x,id.vars="height",variable.name="latitude")
  melt_x$latitude <- as.numeric(as.character(melt_x$latitude))
  melt_x$x <- with(melt_x, value*sin(latitude))
  melt_x$y <- with(melt_x, value*cos(latitude))
  return(melt_x)
})

> melted_arrays[[1]]
  height latitude value         x         y
1      1        0    -1  0.000000 -1.000000
2      2        0    -2  0.000000 -2.000000
3      3        0    -3  0.000000 -3.000000
4      1       90    -4 -3.575987  1.792294
5      2       90    -5 -4.469983  2.240368
6      3       90    -6 -5.363980  2.688442
7      1       45    -7 -5.956325 -3.677254
8      2       45    -8 -6.807228 -4.202576
9      3       45    -9 -7.658132 -4.727898
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who come across this topic later. Not sure where your `x` of `my.fun` come from. Generally, you can access columns by names using `lapply()`. Just like below:

```
lapply(1, my.fun(i, df), df=yourdf)[[1]]
```

Here in `lapply()`, `i` is a must have and just pass your dataframe as an additional parameter `df` and then you are able to reference any columns using `df$any_column_you_want` inside the function.